# How can I see my current missions in Fruit Ninja?

Tags: fruit-ninja

It seems like the only place your current missions are visible is the score screen after you've played a game.  Is there any way to see the missions before playing (e.g. when you first open the app)?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the missions are also displayed on the pause screen.  So you can start a game and immediately pause it to see the missions.  You can then abort the game if you want to change modes/dojos/blades.